# Time-dependent perturbation theory in a degenerate system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, time-evolution

In the derivation of probability transition of time-dependent perturbation theory (see for example  [these notes](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_dep.pdf), from Ben Simons from Cambridge University), I have only encountered treatments of non-degenerate systems, but the result seems independent of whether the system is degenerate or non-degenerate.

In time-independent perturbation theory, the need of treating the degenerate systems in a different way arises from the presence of energy differences present in the denominator of a certain quantity, the coefficients of the expansion of the perturbed eigenvectors. However here no divergence occurs and so I want to know, the derivation of the probability transition for discrete degenerate systems can be treated equivalently to that of non-degenerate systems?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: What *exactly* are you looking for? Do you know Fermi’s golden rule?

Comment: @InertialObserver I do know the Fermi's Golden rule, my question was regarding transitions between degenerate discrete states like in an hydrogen atom, but your point is very good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a late response.  I am describing here what I understand. The reference you have provided in
[http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_dep.pdf](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ebds10/aqp/handout_dep.pdf),
considered two level easy system in the first example. For this system no perturbation theory is required and the result is exact (you can observe perturbation theory means expansion in terms of perturbation, but no such expansion is required in case of two level system).
But for complicated systems the energy terms may or may not appear in the denominator during perturbative expansion, causing problems for degenerate systems. See the following references,
https://alan.ece.gatech.edu/ECE6451/Lectures/ECE6451L9PerturbationTheory.pdf
https://www.southampton.ac.uk/assets/centresresearch/documents/compchem/perturbation_theory.pdf

Thanks to the last reference because of which I can answer this question.